# MVC4 desktop to Mobile view conversion

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mobile

I have build website in mvc4 ASP.net.
Now I want to make mobile version of complete site. What should I use?

I have seen about MVC4 Mobile package in nuget.

Am I required to change all the "View" of my project if I use mobile mvc.?

what procedure do I have to follow to convert it to mobile version?

If there is any other way or other technique which is open source, then please suggest